# Чи є "Подякував" наприкінці листа загальновживаною практикою?

Tags: вживання-слів

Час від часу бачу слово "подякував" як окреме та завершене речення (іноді навіть відокремлене в абзац) десь наприкінці повідомлення. Зазвичай воно зустрічається в тих самих контекстах, де більшість людей зазвичай вживають слово "дякую" чи ще якесь там "спасибі". Воно начебто і не можна вважати це помилкою (людина пише, що вона подякувала, все гаразд), але чомусь ріже око.

Як вважаєте, чи можна вважати використання слова "подякував" замість "дякую" загальновживаною практикою, чи це все ж таки помилка, яку не слід повторювати?

Подя... вибачте, дякую. :-)

Comment: У мене друг так говорить, але мені здається, що використовувати таке в листі можна тільки в неформальному спілкуванні і треба бути з цим обережним, бо можуть сприйняти за нахабство.

Comment: @Yola, цікаво було б почути його бачення (яке значення він надає слову і як часто бачив таке в інших).

Comment: @Sasha запитавсь, виявляється, що він вже й забув, що раніше так казав і сказав, що це жаргон і краще так не казати.

Comment: Особисто я завжди кажу «подякував», коли отримую допомогу від іншої людини

Comment: @RomanMikhol, тобто коли отримали допомогу _не від того, кого пишете_ (мовляв, подякували _третій особі_), — я правильно розумію? (Чи тоді, коли дякуєте співрозмовнику?)

Comment: @Sasha, дякую вам. Дякую за уважність і за розсудливість. Саме завдяки прагненню зрозуміти речі на глибинному рівні, багато питань вже отримало вичерпну відповідь і знання відвідувачів ресурсу не лишилися поверхневими. Відчуття вдячності і поваги можна висловити багатьма словами, а можна і єдиним дієсловом доконаного стану. То ж, подякував :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не бачу підстав для такого вживання:

1. Не бачу його на практиці — шукав у «Генеральному регіонально анотованому корпусі української мови» версії 12:

   - Для «дякую/дякуємо» і «дякую/дякуємо <комусь>» окремим реченням я бачу [багато траплянь](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac12&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&default_attr=word&cql=%3Cs%3E%20%22(?i)%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%83(%D1%8E%7C%D1%94%D0%BC%D0%BE)%22%20%5Btag=%22.*dav.*%22%5D?%20%3C/s%3E&showresults=1).
   - Для «подякував/подякувала» і «подякував/подякувала <комусь>» окремим реченням я бачу [жодного](https://parasol.vmguest.uni-jena.de/grac_crystal/#concordance?corpname=grac12&tab=advanced&queryselector=cql&default_attr=word&cql=%3Cs%3E%20%22(?i)%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0(%D0%B2%7C%D0%BB%D0%B0)%22%20%5Btag=%22.*dav.*%22%5D?%20%3C/s%3E&showresults=1).
2. Не бачу теоретичних причин його вживати з погляду значення: [дякувати](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=25494&page=845) фактично означає «висловлювати подяку»¹, і наприкінці листа автор зазвичай саме висловлює її (у теперішньому часі), а не повідомляє, що колись раніше висловлював.

Але мова — гручка річ: якщо Ви справді бачите часто таке вживання (я припускаю — у якомусь конкретному осередку) і якщо з часом воно поширюватиметься, то теоретично це може стати новою нормою (і значення слова може змінитися з «висловлювати вдячність» на, наприклад, «відчувати вдячність», мовляв, наприкінці листа автор писатиме, що відчув вдячність). Проте поки що такого поширення не бачу.

<sub>¹ Словник української мови у 20 томах каже, що *дякувати* означає не лише «висловлювати, виражати подяку», а й «бути вдячним за щось». Але навіть у цьому разі форма теперішнього часу наприкінці листа доречніша, аніж доконаний вид минулого часу (окрім випадків, коли автор спочатку був вдячний, але на момент написання листа вже не вдячний). Окрім того я особисто не бачу в словнику прикладів, де вживання б підходило під «бути вдячним за щось» і при цьому не підходило під «висловлювати, виражати подяку», — по-моєму, значення «висловлювати, виражати подяку» достатньо.</sub>

Comment: Дієслова доконаного виду вказують на початок, кінець або одноразовість процесу. Їм властиві такі відтінки значення, як результативність, вичерпаність, достатність, інтенсивність, поширеність. Тому у фаховій мові їх уживають для позначання конкретного завершеного (повністю або на певному етапі) процесу, тобто події, яка відбулася у минулому, або має відбутися в майбутньому, коли хочуть підкреслити саме результативність процесу в момент його завершення. http://science.lpnu.ua/uk/terminologiya/vsi-vypusky/visnyk-no-559-2006/diyeslivna-kategoriya-vydu-praktychni-vysnovky-dlya